# Channel Manager - Edit Channels - Blank page

Tags: channel, blank-screen

I updated to EE 5.3.0 from 2.11.9 and cannot edit existing channels anymore.

There is only a blank page without any errors in the console.
I can edit layouts or export but no page is opening to edit the channel.

The url looks like this: https://www.foo.ch/admin.php?/cp/channels/edit/12

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try by adding `$config['debug'] = "1";` in your *config.php*. So, you can display errors and after that try to solve them. In most of the cases these errors are belonging from modules. So, you just need to upgrade the module to solve those module errors.

You can also try below code in your index.php file.

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried both solutions but without result. Just a blank page.